# How does the app engine Search API handle multiword queries?

Tags: google-app-engine

After reading through the documentation I'm still a little unclear of how app engine handles multiword queries on a document. Like, if there a query like `new red bike`, and a document only has the terms `red` and `bike` in it, will it still return the document as a partial match or must all words be present?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API will treat each word as an individual term and return all documents that have the 3 terms in them *somewhere*, essentially converting your query into a `"new" AND "red" AND "bike"`, as correctly outlined by omair_77.

To come full circle - if you want the API to treat the words `new red bike` as one term and do not want it to return any documents with just `new` and `red` and `bike` in it as loose terms, you need to enclose your query with quotation marks, i.e. `"new red bike"`.

Answer (score 1):

search API treats space as "AND" so when you query a word with space like "new red bike" the query will be like "new AND red AND bike". so it will bring the results containing all the three words

Comment: Thanks -- is there a way to format the query with OR statements?